# Заполнение столбца по условию в другом столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть DataFrame:

[image: дф]

Хотелось бы заполнить пропуски в столбце 'living_area' медианой, учитывая количество комнат в квартире (столбец 'rooms').

Попытался реалиизовать функцию, но нормально не заработала, так как исправляла весь df, а не конкретный столбец. Попробовал совсем топорным способом заполнить, чтобы понять процесс и вроде получилось:

```
stud = data[data['rooms']==0]
stud #192 студии
stud['living_area'].median() #медиана студий - 18 метров
stud['living_area'] =  stud['living_area'].fillna(stud['living_area'].median())
stud.isnull().sum() #192 пропуска заполенены медианой 
data[data['rooms']==0] = stud
data.isnull().sum()
data[data['rooms']==0].isnull().sum()
```

Как такую операцию можно красиво записать в функцию для определенного столбца через `apply` с циклом из значений всех квартир? То есть, в таком цикле:

```
for lsquare in list(data['rooms'].unique()):
```

Comment: Добавте пожалуйста данные текстом, а не картинкй.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)

Пример:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
data.loc[data['rooms'] == 0, 'living_area'] = \
    imp_mean.fit_transform(data.loc[data['rooms'] == 0, 'living_area'])
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. А обязательно включать переменную? В цикле это нельзя как-то сделать?

Comment: @aabitokh, циклы?? в Pandas?? уверены что хотите их использовать? ;)

Comment: Ну тут цикл-то общий, он не датафрейм перебирает, а просто меняет значение в функции, так что почему бы и нет)

Comment: @aabitokh, если цикл по __столбцам__, то это нормально

Comment: Ваш код заполняет весь столбец, а не пропущенные значения.

Comment: @aabitokh, обновил ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно получить медианное значение 'living_area' в зависимости от комнат. Затем итерируемся по кол-ву комнат и подставляем в пропущенные значения нужную медиану.

```
 l_room_median = train.pivot_table(values='living_area', index='rooms', aggfunc='median')
 for y in (l_room_median.index):
    train.living_area= np.where((pd.isnull(data['living_area'])) & \
    (train['rooms'] == y), int(l_room_median.loc[y]), int(train['living_area'])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]